# Retreive Mozilla Firefox browser history with powershell

Tags: sqlite, powershell, firefox

I'm trying to fetch Mozilla Firefox browser history from `places.sqlite` with powershell.

This is the query which I'm running, `$mozillapath` variable contains location of `places.sqlite` file.

```
".open $mozillapath
 SELECT datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch'), moz_places.url FROM moz_places, moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id
" | C:\Users\Admin\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3260000\sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3260000\sqlite3.exe
```

I'm getting output in following format:

```
Username : Admin
C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\nr0o1s57.default\\places.sqlite
2019-01-11 15:00:07|https://www.mozilla.org/privacy/firefox/
2019-01-11 15:00:07|https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/
2019-01-11 15:02:28|https://twitter.com/
2019-01-12 12:01:09|https://twitter.com/
2019-01-12 11:36:28|http://google.com/
2019-01-12 11:36:28|http://www.google.com/
2019-01-12 11:36:28|https://www.google.com/
2019-01-12 12:01:03|https://www.amazon.com
```

after saving output in variable i'm not able to format it, I want it as last 7 days history with date and website:

```
Date : 2019-01-11 15:00:07
Site : https://www.mozilla.org/privacy/firefox/
```

Comment: What have you tried to format the output so far? Always include your code even if it doesn't work. This gives us an idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is the output in the variable a single string or an array of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select-Object` - to Skip the first two lines are they aren't history information.

`ConvertFrom-Csv` - Create an object from each line, using the pipe synbol as the delimiter between the properties.

`Select-Object` - just using a calculated property to convert the `Date` from a string into a `datetime` so you can use date calculations to get only last 7 days.

```
Select-Object -Skip 2 |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header 'Date','Site' |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {[datetime]$_.Date}},Site
```

With some test data:

```
$output = @"
Username : Admin
C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\nr0o1s57.default\\places.sqlite
2019-01-11 15:00:07|https://www.mozilla.org/privacy/firefox/
2019-01-11 15:00:07|https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/
2019-01-11 15:02:28|https://twitter.com/
2019-01-12 12:01:09|https://twitter.com/
2019-01-12 11:36:28|http://google.com/
2019-01-12 11:36:28|http://www.google.com/
2019-01-12 11:36:28|https://www.google.com/
2019-01-12 12:01:03|https://www.amazon.com
2019-01-01 12:01:03|https://www.stackoverflow.com
2019-01-02 12:01:03|https://www.superuser.com
"@

# not be needed if your output is an array of strings
$output = $output.Split([Environment]::NewLine, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

# create object from output
$history = $output | Select-Object -Skip 2 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header 'Date','Site' | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {[datetime]$_.Date}},Site

# get only last 7 days
$history | Where-Object -Property Date -GT (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
```

Outputs:

```
Date                Site                                          
----                ----                                          
11/01/2019 15:00:07 https://www.mozilla.org/privacy/firefox/      
11/01/2019 15:00:07 https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/
11/01/2019 15:02:28 https://twitter.com/                          
12/01/2019 12:01:09 https://twitter.com/                          
12/01/2019 11:36:28 http://google.com/                            
12/01/2019 11:36:28 http://www.google.com/                        
12/01/2019 11:36:28 https://www.google.com/                       
12/01/2019 12:01:03 https://www.amazon.com
```

You can then save this to a file:

```
$history | Where-Object -Property Date -GT (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | Out-File history.txt
```

Or use `Format-List` to display it as a list (which then be saved as a file using Out-File):

```
$history | Where-Object -Property Date -GT (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | Format-List
```

```
Date : 11/01/2019 15:00:07
Site : https://www.mozilla.org/privacy/firefox/

Date : 11/01/2019 15:00:07
Site : https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/

Date : 11/01/2019 15:02:28
Site : https://twitter.com/

Date : 12/01/2019 12:01:09
Site : https://twitter.com/

Date : 12/01/2019 11:36:28
Site : http://google.com/

Date : 12/01/2019 11:36:28
Site : http://www.google.com/

Date : 12/01/2019 11:36:28
Site : https://www.google.com/

Date : 12/01/2019 12:01:03
Site : https://www.amazon.com
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't too much work involved provided:

- There is always only two lines of leading info
- There are no bar (`|`) symbols in the text other than the splitter

The following code simply splits the text on newlines, skips the first two, and then does basic parsing on the result.

```
$Str = "Username : Admin
C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\nr0o1s57.default\\places.sqlite
2019-01-11 15:00:07|https://www.mozilla.org/privacy/firefox/
2019-01-11 15:00:07|https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/
2019-01-11 15:02:28|https://twitter.com/
2019-01-12 12:01:09|https://twitter.com/"

$Str -split '[\r\n]+' | Select -Skip 2 | % {
    $D,$S = $_ -split '\|'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($D,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
        Site = $S
    }
}
```

You'll get back something like this.

```
Date                Site                                          
----                ----                                          
11/01/2019 15:00:07 https://www.mozilla.org/privacy/firefox/      
11/01/2019 15:00:07 https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/
11/01/2019 15:02:28 https://twitter.com/                          
12/01/2019 12:01:09 https://twitter.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option it gonna be to use the SQLite assembly to query the data from the sqlite database.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("$($PSScriptRoot)\System.Data.SQLite.dll") | Out-Null
```

For selecting the "places" database I am using this:

```
$Path = "$Env:systemdrive\Users\$ENV:USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*places.sqlite"
$HistFile = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Sort-Object -Descending -Property Length | Select-Object FullName -First 1
```

Open a connection on the DB file:

```
$conn = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$($HistFile.FullName)"
$conn.Open()
```

Select the results and output the result to a Grid:

```
$channelList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT datetime(moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000,'unixepoch') AS VisitDate, moz_places.url FROM moz_places, moz_historyvisits WHERE moz_places.id = moz_historyvisits.place_id"
$sqlite_datareader = $cmd.ExecuteReader();
while ($sqlite_datareader.Read()) {
    $dataRow = [pscustomobject]@{
        Url          = $sqlite_datareader["url"].ToString()
        VisitDate    = [datetime]$sqlite_datareader["VisitDate"]
    }
    $channelList.Add($dataRow) | Out-Null
}

$channelList | Out-GridView
```